# Proof that for $x,y\in G$ and $y=xa$ for some $a\in H$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that $xH=yH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove that for $x,y\in G$ and $y=xa$ for some $a\in H$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that $xH=yH$.

I think I am sort of on the right lines but I lack confidence I'd like to have this confirmed (and the iffy parts cleaned up) or to be shown it is wrong (which I don't think it is)

I want to do this by showing $yH\subset xH$ and $yH \supset xH$ as then $yH=xH$ must be true.

My proof starts as follows:

If $y=xa$ then $yh=xah\forall h\in H$ by the closure of $H$ both $h$ and $ah\in H$, this means (I've backspaced a lot, it is just nonsensical)

I want to say something like "but $ah\in H\forall h\in H$ too!" but I can't get from there to that subset relation I want.

If I say "$yh$ is the very definition of the left coset of y in H in G (am I saying this right?) then $xah$ is the same coset, therefore the two are the same" but this feels wrong, I want to use the word isomorphism and use $y=xa$ in the form $yh=x(ah)$ but I wouldn't feel confident.

BUT if I do manage to do it my way I can get "both sides" of the subset relation from $yh=xah$ and $xh=ya^{-1}h$ which is why I think there's a proof to be had.

Comment: $yH = x(aH) = xH$.

Comment: $xH=yH\iff y^{-1}xH=y^{-1}yH\iff aH=H$ and the map $H\to H$, $h\mapsto ah$ is a bijection (with inverse $h\mapsto a^{-1}h$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I don't really consider that a proof, it uses knowledge that cosets are either equal or disjoint, I am doing this to try and prove that, which is why I wanted to do inclusion, if you could upvote Spock's answer that'd be great, he deserves the credit.

Comment: @AlecTeal, I don't see what you're saying. All this needs is $h \in H \implies hH = H$ which is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea for showing inclusion is a good one. You just have to make it more precise. 
We have $y=xa$ thus, $yH=xaH$. Let $m\in yH \implies m\in xaH\implies m=xaa'$ for some $a'\in H$ but $aa'\in H$ so let $aa'=a''$ for some $a''\in H$. Therefore $m=xa''\implies m\in xH$. So $yH\subseteq xH$. 
You can argue similarly for the other direction.